# word open xml c# image quality drops

Tags: c#, image, openxml-sdk

I am generating images and, using word open xml, putting them into template word document. C# adds additional 'features', though.

Lets say we have one color square. C# would 'upgrade' picture with 1 pixel width light borders. Can I avoid this behaviour?

Code to replace tagged picture with an image:

```
 protected static void fillImage(SdtBlock imageControl, int ID)
    {
        // Remove the placeholder =========================================
        imageControl.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<ShowingPlaceholder>().Remove();
        // Embed image ====================================================
        var relationshipID = "someName" + ID;
        ImagePart imagePart = _document.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, relationshipID);
        var ending = ".png";
        var folder = _imageFolder;
        var imagePath = Path.Combine(folder, _name, "image" + ID + ending);

        // Resize =========================================================
        //widthInPixels / HorizontalResolutionInDPI * 914400
        int width;
        int height;
        double ratio;
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath, true))
        {
                some code to set width and height (from image.height and image.width)
        }

        var extent = imageControl.Descendants<WP.Extent>().Single();
        extent.Cx = width;
        extent.Cy = height;
        var extents = imageControl.Descendants<DW.Extents>().Single();
        extents.Cx = width;
        extents.Cy = height;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }
        // Replace the relationship ID
        var blip = imageControl.Descendants<DW.Blip>().Single();
        blip.Embed = relationshipID;
    }
```

To save:

```
       public void RemoveContentControlsAndKeepContents(Document document)
    {
        if (document == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("document");
        }

        CustomXmlPartCore customXmlPartCore = new CustomXmlPartCore(this.NamespaceUri);
        CustomXmlPart customXmlPart = customXmlPartCore.GetCustomXmlPart(document.MainDocumentPart);
        XmlDocument customPartDoc = new XmlDocument();

        if (customXmlPart != null)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(customXmlPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
            {
                customPartDoc.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        RemoveContentControlsAndKeepContents(document.Body, customPartDoc.DocumentElement);
        document.Save();
    }
```

Comment: can you clarify your question further ?

Comment: show your code that adds picture and save document.

Comment: Are you resizing the image at any point?  Some of Windows's poorer quality resizing algorithms will leave a blurry edge around a solid color image.

Comment: I really do and I am not proud of it. If I do nothing, the final image would be the size of 'tag image'. So I change the size of tagged picture to be as close as the one I generated. Is there a way to keep the exact size of generated image?